# Notification addon for Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, notifications

Outlook 2010 will not show notification envelope for IMAP accounts (which is a horrible bug IMO but that's the reality right now), are there any good add-ons that would "fix" this? I'm primarily after something that could add an envelope in the sys tray as Outlook 2007 used to do out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Emil Estanov has done one which works pretty well and its free!:

http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/OutlookEmailNotifier/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link:

http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/outlook-2010-imap-notification-alert/

Comment: This one looks good...+1

Comment: ... but it doesn't answer the question. I am not after a desktop alert but after some kind of permanent notification like Outlook can do for Exchange accounts.

Answer (score 0):

[Mail Alert](http://www.bettasoft.net/mailalert/) provides this functionality although it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

**MS released a [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2516474) that fixes this bug:**

Description of the Outlook 2010 hotfix package (outlook-x-none): April 26, 2011

> Issues that this hotfix package fixes:
>
> - ...
> - When you use an IMAP account to log on to Outlook 2010, the envelope icon
>     does not show in the notification
>     area. Additionally, no sound is played
>     when you receive an email message.
> - ...

via [MSOutlook.info](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/498)